# k-mean clustering of week-times

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means

I have data of meeting times.  The data has weekday and hour of the day.

I want to cluster the meeting times (I have reason to believe there are two different kinds of meetings that tend to occur at cluster means) into two clusters.

I want to use k-means, but I am not 100% sure of a sensible data arrangement.  I have reason to believe that weekend vs weekday is probably a meaningful distinction, so the distance from Friday to Saturday should probably be a bit more than be more than the distance from Saturday to Sunday. (Right? Or I could add in a third dimension, weekend dummy.)

I was thinking it makes sense to use (day, hour, weekend dummy(?)) to cluster.  When I standardize, the algorithm puts too much influence on weekend vs. weekday it seems, and separates the clustered almost entirely that way.

My question is this: is there a way to still consider the influence of weekday vs. weekend but not have it overly weighted in the clustering.  Should I consider a different standardization of each variable?  Potentially manipulating the variance by scaling?

Comment: Week is usually considered cyclic data. Is it alright to treat it as linear (just ask - I don't know your situation)?

Comment: How is cyclic data usually handled?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use clustering.

This data is better handled via visualization.

Plot a 7x24 activity heat map, draw the clusters using rectangles, and maybe measure the significance using some statistical model.

K-means will not work well for cylindric (repetitive) data; and you can't easily integrate information like weekday vs. weekend. It's just not a good match.

Clustering like k-means is nothing but a heuristic; and **a visual approach *will* do much better**.

Comment: There are too many sets of meetings though to do visual inspection...is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: Can you suggest actual algorithm names that can be applied to many data sets of meetings?

Comment: Can't you draw all of them in one figure? I'm not aware of an algorithm that works really well on cyclical data like yours, and which can take weekend vs. weekday into account, too.

Comment: There are about 40 meetings per dataset and there are 129,000 datasets.

Comment: HOw many of the 129,000 are trivial? E.g. how many have more than 1 unique meeting time? Usually at least 100000 of them will be of the "every friday 9-10, no exceptions" kind. In how many cases is there one option less frequent than 90%? All these are trivially to solve without clustering.

Comment: All of them have more than 1 unique time.  There were 500,000 datasets before that. The remaining 129k all have at least 15. Why do you presume to know about my data?  These meetings are not corporate meetings.  I'm not at liberty to reveal exactly what they are but calling them meetings should be sufficient.  I am positive that what I have said so far is correct about the parameters of the problem.

Comment: (Sorry to be snippy, I didn't see you wrote the word "usually")

Comment: And apparently my estimate wasn't too far off either, since apparently 75% of your data were such cases.
But the details on what the best approaches are are - unfortunately - hard without knowing the data characteristics. Maybe coclustering time slots and weekdays yields best results. Maybe not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18944/discussion-between-robbieboy74-and-anony-mousse).